# How does core handle the different time zones?

Tags: datetime

Here is my situation, I have a website where the content author(i.e who has his preferred time zone as PST in US) had created the node of one content type which had an event in New York(i.e a different time zone EST in US). So he adds the content in that node and set the time for the event according to his time zone(i.e PST) as 12 PM.

Then a customer comes onto site to check for the event on the UI in his place(New York) and sees the event is at 12 PM EST(i.e JS takes the preferred time zone of the OS where the user has set) and when he goes to the event he figures out the event was 3 hours later the time which he saw in the website.

Is there a way that Drupal can handle the events in different time zones to be shown to the anonymous users in their respective time zones?

Comment: By concept an anonymous user does not have a personal timezone, that's why it is called anonymous. Only registered users can set a personal timezone.

Comment: Drupal 8 gives you the options to set which time zone should be used for the entered time. Next to the time recorded in the field you can print out the time zone. Won't that be enough for your users to orient themselves? You can look for changing how your date/time field is printed out under "Manage Display" of the Content Type. Views also support showing which time zone should be used. You can show the same field 3 times if you like, each in different time zone. That way users don't need to calculate for themselves, they just recognize their time zone.